# Redirect git:// to https://

Tags: git, firefox-os

For some strange reason my university has blocked git port (I think 9418).
So I can't clone any of the source repos starts with git://.
For github I can replace git:// with https:// and clone them.
But when I was trying to clone the Mozilla B2G source,It requests some parts from www.codeaurora.org/‎ which has no https:// repo support.
Is there anyway to get around this and clone the source?

Answer (score -1):

Fortunately, the Mozilla B2G [repositories](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g) are also hosted on GitHub. You are then able to clone them via HTTPS.

For example, to clone [Gaia](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia): `git clone https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia.git`

Comment: I'v been using that one.But when I try to build it it fetches some more code from www.codeaurora.org. That's the troubled part!

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.